# Open windows Explorer and select multiple items in it

Tags: python, subprocess

Suppose I have a folder path as a string:

```
dir_: str = r'path\to\a\folder'
```

and some items (either files or folders) inside of that folder as strings (excluding their path) like:

```
items: list[str] = [
    'foo.py'
    'bar.exe'
    'baz']
```

My question is: how I can open Windows Explorer at `dir_` and select `items` inside of it?
Thank you  an advanced.

I tried the following:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file"')
```

But it only selects one and only one item in the Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `win32com.shell`.

```py
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

def open_folder_and_select_items(path, files_to_select=[]):
    path_pidl = shell.SHILCreateFromPath(path, shellcon.SFGAO_FOLDER)[0]
    desktop = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
    selected = []
    flags = shellcon.SHGDN_INFOLDER|shellcon.SHGDN_FORPARSING
    
    for item in desktop.BindToObject(path_pidl, None, shell.IID_IShellFolder):
        display_name = desktop.GetDisplayNameOf(item, flags)
        if display_name in files_to_select:
            selected.append(item)
    
    # If an empty list is passed to SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems, Windows opens 
    # the parent folder and selects the folder. To avoid this, pass a list of 
    # only path_pidl.
    if not selected:
        selected = [path_pidl]
    
    shell.SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(path_pidl, selected)

dir_ = r"C:\Users\Sleve McDichael\Downloads"
items = ("Bobson Dugnutt highlights.mp4", "Mike Truk highlights.mp4")
open_folder_and_select_items(dir_, items)
```

You should be able to do it with `win32com.client` as well. I'll update my answer with code tomorrow if I get time.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a list of file paths (full paths). Then, add the file paths to the bash command:

```py
file_paths = [os.path.join(dir_, item) for item in items]

arg_str = '"' + ','.join(file_paths) + '"'

subprocess.Popen('explorer /select,' + arg_str)
```

Comment: It does not work.